# jQuery datepicker setDate to value from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have problem with `datepicker` `setDate` option (I need to use server date in datepicker). I have display current date from server in that format (html source):

```
<div id="cur-date">27/11/2013</div>
```

In jquery script I try to set the `setDate` using this code:

```
$('#date_from, #date_to').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    defaultDate: '+1d', 
    minDate: '+1d'
    }).datepicker('setDate', '#cur-date');
```

But it didn't work.
Any suggestion what is wrong?

Comment: whats not working? are u trying to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/PJ956/?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9wcVV/1/

Comment: Yes, but when you change date in windows clock to 4.11.2013 in the datepicker you will have current date also on 4.11

Comment: try to change this line 
}).datepicker('setDate', $('#cur-date').html());

Comment: Arun P Johny - your solution works pretty fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first use **text()** not **val()**

**val()** is use for input type

```
$('#date_from, #date_to').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
}).datepicker("setDate", $("#cur-date").text());
```

Comment: I set $('#date_from, #date_to').datepicker("setDate", "1"); and now works fine :)

Comment: great @Adrian feel happy that you get your solution

Answer (score 0):

Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents `one month` and `seven days` from `today`.Since you are added +1d it does not show the current date. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.

```
$('#date_from, #date_to').datepicker({
    defaultDate: '+1d', 
    minDate: '0'
 }).datepicker('setDate', '#cur-date');

Try removing the `minDate: '+1d'` or try commenting that part or even changing it to 0.
```

Working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Uv8c5/

Comment: Try to change widows date

Comment: Go to your MS Windows date&time settings, and change date to ex. 4.11.2013

Answer (score 0):

Use datepicker with these parameters

```
$('#date_from, #date_to').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yy',
  autoclose: true,
  forceParse:true,
  pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
 startDate: $("#cur-date").text()
});
```